# undefined function 'xmls:getString'

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to run a small program with ballerina. Here's my code.

```html
import ballerina.lang.system;
import ballerina.lang.xmls;
function main(string[] args) {
 system:println("Hello, World!");
 string xmlvar = "<bookstore>\n<book category=\"cooking\">\n  <title lang=\"en\">Everyday Italian</title>\n  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>\n  <year>2005</year>\n  <price>30.00</price>\n</book>\n<bookstore>";
 string var1 = xmls:getString(xmlvar, "/bookstore/book[1]");
 system:println(var1);
 
}
```

When I try to run above, I get the error undefined function 'xmls:getString'.

I have already imported ballerina.lang.xmls.

Any idea ?

Comment: You are trying to pass a ballerina string value to the getString method signature hence the error.
`getString(xml msg, string xPath)`

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following.

```
import ballerina.lang.system;
import ballerina.lang.xmls;

function main(string[] args) {

    xml payload = `<bookstore><book category="cooking">  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  <year>2005</year>  <price>30.00</price></book></bookstore>`;

    system:println(xmls:getString(payload, "/bookstore/book[1]"));
}
```

Also correct your end tag to `</bookstore>`

Please refer documentation for more information.
http://ballerinalang.org/docs/api/0.8/ballerina.lang.xmls.html#getString